# While parsing a JSON, strange exception occurs as :This is not a JSON Array

Tags: java, json, exception

I've got a broblem wih JSON parser.
Here is the JSON response from server.

```
{
 "coord"  : {"lon":37.62,"lat":55.75},
 "weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"test","icon":"04d"}],
 "base"   :"stations",
 "main"   :{"temp":12.76,"pressure":1007,"humidity":93,"tempmin":12,"tempmax":14},
 "visibility":6000,
 "wind"   :{"speed":4,"deg":300},
 "clouds" :{"all":75},
 "dt":1504881000,
 "sys"    :{"type":1,"id":7325,"message":0.0064,"country":"RU","sunrise":1504838942,"sunset":1504886617},
 "id"     :524901,
 "name"   :"City",
 "cod"    :200
 }
```

And java code ....

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import com.google.gson.*;

public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
try {
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject json = parser.parse("JSON responce here").getAsJsonObject();
JsonArray weather = json.get("weather").getAsJsonArray(); //no problem
int visibility = json.get("visibility").getAsInt();
int id = json.get("id").getAsInt();
int dt = json.get("dt").getAsInt();
String name = json.get("name").getAsString(); 
JsonArray clouds = json.get("clouds").getAsJsonArray(); //here is the problem
JsonArray main = json.get("main").getAsJsonArray(); //here is the problem
} catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The problem is ... when I compile I've got **java.lang.IllegalStateException: This is not a JSON Array.** on **JsonArray clouds = json.get("clouds").getAsJsonArray();** and others lines like this.

BUT  **JsonArray weather = json.get("weather").getAsJsonArray();** is OK...

I don't understand what is happening... but the array "weather" node has no problem... totally. Please, help me... what's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it is a Json Object

```
JsonObject json = json.get("clouds").getAsJsonObject()
```

It will work...

Or you can change the data as given below

```
{
 "coord"  : {"lon":37.62,"lat":55.75},
 "weather":{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"test","icon":"04d"},
 "base"   :"stations",
 "main"   :{"temp":12.76,"pressure":1007,"humidity":93,"tempmin":12,"tempmax":14},
 "visibility":6000,
 "wind"   :{"speed":4,"deg":300},
 "clouds" :[{"all":75}],
 "dt":1504881000,
 "sys"    :{"type":1,"id":7325,"message":0.0064,"country":"RU","sunrise":1504838942,"sunset":1504886617},
 "id"     :524901,
 "name"   :"City",
 "cod"    :200
 }
```